# Passing DGV Table to a Report Viewer in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, pagination, reportviewer

I have some code for pagination DGV , It is working properly..But recently i need to pass the DGV table to a report viewer. 
I found a snippet to do this job but with errors.. Like the Report viewer shows the table header only without data or the data of some columns only,This is my code to passing DGV table to Report viewer

```
 Form8.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
Form8.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Report1.rdlc")

Dim rds = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", DataGridView1.DataSource) 
Form8.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)

'Form8.ReportViewer1.Refresh()
'Form8.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
'Form8.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

 If Form8.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
 Else
 End If
 Form8.Dispose()
```

I enabled to fix that by filling the DGV again before going to the report viewer ,By adding these lines

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection(cs) 
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from Emp")
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "Emp")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Emp")
```

It is OK for a DGV with one page but if i have more than one page the first page only pass

I tried to use My pagination code to solve the issue but i failed ..It has a Datatable "dtTemp" cloned from DataTable "dtsource" in order to divide the DGV into pages.
Here is my code to make pagination to DGV it works like a charm.

```
''' <summary>
''' The next lines are for making pagination to datagridview table, I will explain it briefly 
'''page size TextBox,It's for determine the number of the rows that i want it to appear to the user on the page,and i make the user change this number as he want from(1 row on the page to 100 rows only) the default is 25 rows
'''TextBox to DIsplay page number, It enables the user to show the whole number of pages and what is the current page,
'''(i.e) if DGV table results 200 rows and he write in page size TextBox 25 , He wiil have 8 pages.
'''And Four pictureboxes as (first,next,previous and last Buttons) To enable user to browse between pages,
'''You will see in every PictureBox the btnFill Button to fill the DGV again before loading the page by LoadPage(),And the Sub LoadPage() To load the cloned DataTable. 
'''The Function CheckFillButton() just for check if the btnFill is clicked or not in order to fill the DGV.
'''Really it is a nice code to make DGV divides into Pages.
'''Every Select Case statements are for avoiding errors ,I faced it during using this pretty snippet   
''' </summary>
Public dtSource As DataTable
Public PageCount As Integer
Public maxRec As Integer
Public pageSize As Integer
Public currentPage As Integer
Public recNo As Integer

    Sub LoadPage()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim startRec As Integer
        Dim endRec As Integer
        Dim dtTemp As DataTable

        Select Case True
            Case DataGridView1.RowCount = Nothing

                Exit Sub
        End Select

        'Duplicate or clone the source table to create the temporary table.
        dtTemp = dtSource.Clone

        If currentPage = PageCount Then
            'MsgBox("currentPage = PageCount")
            endRec = maxRec
        Else
            endRec = pageSize * currentPage
        End If

        startRec = recNo

        'Copy the rows from the source table to fill the temporary table.
        For i = startRec To endRec - 1
            dtTemp.ImportRow(dtSource.Rows(i))
            recNo = recNo + 1
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dtTemp.DefaultView

        DisplayPageInfo()

    End Sub

    Private Function CheckFillButton() As Boolean

        'Check if the user clicks the "Fill Grid" button.
        If pageSize = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("PLS determine the size of pages", "Hint")
            CheckFillButton = False
        Else
            CheckFillButton = True
        End If

    End Function

    Sub DisplayPageInfo()
        txtDisplayPageNo.Text = "Page " & currentPage.ToString & "/ " & PageCount.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click
        'As button first
        Label5.Text = "first"
        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return
        Select Case True
            Case Val(txtPageSize.Text) = 0 Or txtPageSize.Text = ""
                MsgBox("items cannot be zero", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")

                txtPageSize.Text = "25"
                Exit Sub
        End Select

        ' Check if you are already at the first page.
        If currentPage = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are at the First Page!")
            Return
        End If

        currentPage = 1
        recNo = 0

        LoadPage()

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.Click
        'As button next
        Label5.Text = "next"
        'If the user did not click the "Fill Grid" button then Return
        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return
        Select Case True
            Case Val(txtPageSize.Text) = 0 Or txtPageSize.Text = ""
                MsgBox("items cannot be zero", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")

                txtPageSize.Text = "25"
                Exit Sub
        End Select

        'Check if the user clicked the "Fill Grid" button.
        If pageSize = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Set the Page Size, and then click the button!")
            Return
        End If

        currentPage = currentPage + 1

        If currentPage > PageCount Then
            currentPage = PageCount

            'Check if you are already at the last page.
            If recNo = maxRec Then
                MessageBox.Show("You are at the Last Page!")

                Return
            End If
        End If

        Select Case True
            Case currentPage <= 1
                MsgBox("Your are in the same page " + vbCrLf +
                       "Try to divide it into pages",
                       MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                Exit Sub
        End Select

        LoadPage()

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click
        'As button previous
        Label5.Text = "previous"
        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return
        Select Case True
            Case Val(txtPageSize.Text) = 0 Or txtPageSize.Text = ""
                MsgBox("items cannot be zero", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                'txtPageSize.Focus()
                txtPageSize.Text = "25"
                Exit Sub
        End Select


        If currentPage = PageCount Then
            recNo = pageSize * (currentPage - 2)
        End If

        currentPage = currentPage - 1

        'Check if you are already at the first page.
        If currentPage < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are at the First Page!")

            currentPage = 1
            Return
        ElseIf currentPage = 1 Then
            'MessageBox.Show("current page = 1")
            recNo = pageSize
        Else
            recNo = pageSize * (currentPage - 1)
        End If

        'this select solve a problem to fill the grid
        Select Case True
            Case currentPage <= 1
                MsgBox("Your are in the page 1 " ,
                       MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                btnFill_Click(sender, e)

                Exit Sub
        End Select

        LoadPage()

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
        'As button last

        Label5.Text = "last"
        If Not CheckFillButton() Then Return
        Select Case True
            Case Val(txtPageSize.Text) = 0 Or txtPageSize.Text = ""
                MsgBox("items cannot be zero", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")

                txtPageSize.Text = "25"
                Exit Sub
        End Select

        ' Check if you are already at the last page.
        If recNo = maxRec Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are at the Last Page!", "Hint")
            Return
        End If

        currentPage = PageCount

        recNo = pageSize * (currentPage - 1)

        LoadPage()
        Movements(PictureBox2, 0.05)

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtPageSize_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPageSize.TextChanged
        If Val(txtPageSize.Text) > 100 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Select Case True
            Case Val(txtPageSize.Text) = 0 Or txtPageSize.Text = ""
                MsgBox("Items cannot be Zero", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
                txtPageSize.Text = "25"
                Exit Sub
        End Select
        btnFill_Click(sender, e)


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFill_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFill.Click

                Using conn As New SqlConnection(cs)
                    conn.Open()
                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from Emp")
                        'cmd.Parameters.Add("@a", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Val(TextBox5.Text)
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        cmd.Connection = conn

                        'Set the DataAdapter's query.
                        Using ds As New DataSet(), da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

                            ' Fill the DataSet.
                            da.Fill(ds, "Emp")
                            'DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Emp")
                            ' Set the source table.
                            dtSource = ds.Tables("Emp")

                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using

                'Set the start and max records. 
                pageSize = CInt(Val(txtPageSize.Text))
                maxRec = dtSource.Rows.Count

                PageCount = maxRec \ pageSize

                ' Adjust the page number if the last page contains a partial page.
                If (maxRec Mod pageSize) > 0 Then
                    PageCount = PageCount + 1
                End If

                'Initial seeings
                currentPage = 1
                recNo = 0

                ' Display the content of the current page.
                LoadPage()

   End Sub
```

The question is how to pass every page of DGV to a Report viewer, (i.e) when i browse between DGV pages ,How can i pass only the page that i'm already on it(it's only consists of 25 rows as the page size says).The above code load the whole table again to DGV then it passes the Whole rows.
Hope i find help here

Comment: After searching, The good way to perform this job is making a datatable then add the columns of the database columns to it then after the datagridview is populated with data , Looping in Datagridview Rows ,In order to ensure that every page pass to the report viewer without any missing of data . I explain it in the next comment

Comment: Dim gdt As New DataTable
        gdt.Columns.Add("ID")
        gdt.Columns.Add("EName")
        gdt.Columns.Add("Tel")
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1        gdt.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value,
                        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value,
                        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
Next
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc" 
Dim rds = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", gdt)        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)